# Why is 'createElement' adding extra tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, createelement

If I add a row to a table with an existing `th` row

```js
y=document.createElement('tr');
z=document.createElement('td');
z.append(document.createTextNode('abc'));
y.append(z);
x.append(y);
console.log(x.innerHTML);
```

```html
<table id="x">
<tr><th>xyz</th></tr>
</table>
```

I get

```
<tbody><tr><th>xyz</th></tr></tbody><tr><td>abc</td></tr>
```

from `innerHTML`, but this has added a `tbody` tag.

I wanted

```
<tr><th>xyz</th></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr>
```

Comment: This is the browser attempting to fix "bad" markup. Because of the way you've written your table, tbody is required. See "Tag omission" in [<tbody>: The Table Body element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody). (Also, my experience has been that browsers include tbody anyway, even when it's not strictly required.)

Comment: What you want is not valid HTML. A `th` element cannot have a `td` element as child.

Comment: @trincot; okay, i've  fixed that, but it still adds a `tbody` which I don't want. I've since fixed this problem, but I don't see why `tbody` is being added when I didn't specify it.